# Wrap boilerplate wcf client code

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I have to add header to wcf service call.

I've implemented it this way:

```
var client = new ServiceReference1.HeaderConsumeClient("NetTcpBinding_IHeaderConsume");
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    Guid apiKey = Guid.NewGuid();
    MessageHeader<Guid> mhg = new MessageHeader<Guid>(apiKey);
    MessageHeader untyped = mhg.GetUntypedHeader("apiKey", "ns");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untyped);

    var res = client.GetData(1);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

But i'd like to make general solution without such boilerplate code at every service call.

The most common way, i think - is to **make my own TT4 template** and wrap every call in generated proxies.

But before it will be done i want to know, **is there a some other ways to override or decorate wcf generated classes methods?**

**For example** - i can use unity and register implementation of this service interface and add interceptor to all calls to this instance. But it looks a bit overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a custom Endpoint Behavior to execute a common action on each service call. Also you can write custom service and operation behaviors.

For instance you can implement a `IClientMessageInspector` and using `BeforeSend` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest(v=vs.110).aspx), you can manipulate the message to be sent.

There is an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx) in the msdn.

Comment: Looks that its qute clear and configurable solution. I will try it